# PiXhost's API- upload images

Tags: python, python-3.x, rest

I'm trying to use PiXhost's api to upload images. Every time I request something from `https://api.pixhost.to/images` it always returns `400 Bad request`. Their API documentation uses python unirest package, but I can't install it as it seems to use too old code.

Am I doing something wrong here?

[Link to documentation](http://pixhost.to/api/index.html?python#upload-image)

my code:

````
import requests
headers = {
    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8",
    "Accept": "application/json"
}
params = {
    "content_type": "0",
    "max_th_size": "420"
}
files = {
    "img": open("image.jpg", mode="rb")
}

response = requests.post("https://api.pixhost.to/images", headers=headers, params=params, files=files)```
````

Comment: show your code, what you are trying to do, my guess is it is related to 'POST' request type...

Comment: Added the answer

Comment: could you upvote also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import requests

url = "https://api.pixhost.to/images"

payload={'content_type': '0',
'max_th_size': '420'}
files={
    'img': ('1.JPG', open('C:/Users/prave/Desktop/1.JPG', 'rb')),
    'content_type': '0',
    'max_th_size': '420'
}
headers = {

}

response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, files=files)

print(response)
```

Here you go

output :

Response 200

**Issue with your code:**

THe endpoint expects formdata , you are passing query parameter

**So how did i figure it out**

[image]

goto documentation and click curl tab to get curl equalent code:

Now goto postman and click import>Raw text > paste  the curl , and click continue and then import

This creates the request for you

[image]

Now goto body and select img type as file and upload the file:

[image]

Now click code and generate equalent curl and python request code:

[image]

[image]

THe generated python code had few isseus one was to remove header completely and then to remove one slash from the file name.

Comment: Pleare don't post images of text; see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: its not text its the output screenshot from prompt!

Comment: It's a screenshot of text, yes. How could a screenshot *possibly* provide any value over a simple copy/paste of the actual text here? Consider also the numerous usability problems behind the link.

Comment: Changed it to text

Answer (score 2):

Just a quick test, I managed to get it done via cURL

```
curl -X POST --include "https://api.pixhost.to/images" \
  -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8' \
  -H 'Accept: application/json' \
  -F 'img=@test1.jpg' \
  -F 'content_type=0' \
  -F 'max_th_size=420'
```

https://pixhost.to/show/39/178828640_test1.jpg

Note: the `test1` image is in the same folder when I running the script

I also receive 400 status code without a body when removing the @ before the URL (so check you URL again)

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
```

Comment: Works, now I just need to convert it to python using requests library.